# Spring MVC java based configuration [The requested resource is not available.] Problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

**I'm struggling with SpringMVC configurations based on java
I don't know where is the problem but the controller showing**

> **description** : The requested resource is not available.

*Here is my code :*
**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.lucia</groupId>
<artifactId>springtesting</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-testing</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <spring.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>springtesting</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version> <!-- or whatever current version -->
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**AppInitializer.java**

```
package com.lucia.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
package com.lucia.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.lucia")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");
}

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.lucia.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.lucia.model.User;

@Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView hello(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName("Test User name");
    mv.addObject("name", user.getUserName());
    mv.setViewName("home");
    return mv;
}
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.lucia.model;

public class User {
private String userName;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

**And Finally this is my home.jsp**

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>Hello : ${name}
</body>
</html>
```

**Someone help me i'm new to java and i'm stuck at this configurations.**

[This is my project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR98X.png)

[This is the error that shown as a output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDeDr.png)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp I guess your directory structure maybe wrong. Your ```WebMvcConfig``` could be easily done be settng propperties, see point 3.

Comment: it's java based config most of the online shows config like this @ThiloSchwarz

Answer (score 0):

when I tried with your configuration, I had to add below dependency
then it worked fine

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: its not working @RanjitSahoo